# Installation of SBT's alternative entry points fails due to a missing repo

Tags: scala, sbt

Per https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Scripts.html I am trying to install sbt's alternative entry points via conscript. I get

```
~> cs sbt/sbt --branch 1.2.1
Repository not found on github
```

I can see https://github.com/sbt/sbt so am puzzled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking at the repository there is no branch `1.2.1`, the most similar is `1.2.x`.

It works using:

```
~> cs sbt/sbt --branch 1.2.x
```